# Pandas panel axes swapping when using panel.mean

Tags: numpy, pandas

I'm trying to understand this weird behavior when using pandas panels. If I take the mean along the major_axis or minor_axis of a panel, the axes seem to get swapped.

```
>>> panel = pd.Panel(np.random.rand(10,20,30))
>>> print(panel.mean(axis=0))
(20, 30)
>>> print(panel.mean(axis=1))
(30, 10)
>>> print(panel.mean(axis=2))
(20, 10)
```

I would have thought that for the last two, the output shapes should be (10, 30) and (10, 20) respectively. This is how it works for a 3D-numpy array, but maybe there is some conceptual difference between a pandas Panel and a numpy array that I'm not getting...

Is this the correct behavior? Can somebody explain why it should be like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be useful to think of a `DataFrame` as a collection of `Series`, where each `Series` is a column in the `DataFrame`.

When you take the mean along `axis=1`, you obtain a `Series` with 30 elements for each of the 10 items in the `Panel`.   If you collect these 10 `Series` you obtain a `DataFrame` with 30 rows and 10 columns.

Similarly , when you take the mean along `axis=2`,  you end up with a `Series` of length 20 for each of the 10 items in the panel.   Collecting these 10 `Series` together gives you a `DataFrame` with 20 rows and 10 columns.

When you calculate the mean along `axis=0`, you obtain the average item, which is expected to have the same shape as each item in the panel, i.e. 20 by 30.

Below some code that may help elucidate my point:

```
In [1]: panel = pd.Panel(np.random.rand(10,20,30))

# Note that for a single item in the panel, the mean along 
# either of its axes is a `Series`:

In [2]: type(panel[0].mean(axis=0))
Out[2]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [3]: type(panel[0].mean(axis=0))
Out[3]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [3]: panel[0].mean(axis=0)
Out[3]:
0     0.569390
1     0.497762
2     0.616333
3     0.608153
4     0.524008
5     0.478621
6     0.492827
7     0.461240
8     0.573557
9     0.654757
10    0.541066
11    0.572929
12    0.482214
13    0.576898
14    0.362965
15    0.493355
16    0.491790
17    0.567756
18    0.426404
19    0.514235
20    0.416983
21    0.455843
22    0.603592
23    0.387520
24    0.470060
25    0.506414
26    0.545156
27    0.525211
28    0.526378
29    0.486419
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Discussion on GitHub here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8906

I recommend you checkout out XRay - it's built on top of pandas for >=3 dimensional data